# 404 Http error handler in Asp.Net MVC (RC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, http-status-code-404

How can I Handler 404 errors without the framework throwing an Exception 500 error code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://jason.whitehorn.ws/2008/06/17/Friendly-404-Errors-In-ASPNET-MVC.aspx gives the following explanation:

Add a wildcard routing rule as your final rule:

```
routes.MapRoute("Error", 
                "{*url}", 
                new { controller = "Error", action = "Http404" });
```

Any request that doesn't match another rule gets routed to the Http404 action of the Error controller, which you also need to configure:

```
public ActionResult Http404(string url) {
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    ViewData["url"] = url;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, The above linked post is returning a 404 (oh the irony). 

The new address is: http://jason.whitehorn.ws/2008/06/17/Friendly-404-Errors-In-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Comment: The only problem here is that so much matches the typical /{controller}/{action}/{id} route. To get around the problem, I explicitly defined all my routes and got rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the link doesn't work. Even http://jason.whitehorn.ws/ is not accessible :|

Comment: This is fine for situations where routes don't match, but doesn't help when an id is not valid for example...

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn 404 again

Answer (score 9):

You can also override HandleUnknownAction within your controller in the cases where a request does match a controller, but doesn't match an action. The default implementation does raise a 404 error.

Comment: Good idea. Check out this solution which incorporates a `HandleUnknownAction` override: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095

Answer (score 4):

throw new HttpException(404, "Resource Not Found");

Answer (score 0):

With MVC 3 you can return HttpNotFound() to properly return a 404.

Like this:

```
public ActionResult Download(string fontName)
{
    FontCache.InitalizeFonts();

    fontName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fontName);

    var font = FontCache.GetFontByName(fontName);
    if (font == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(font);
}
```