# Redirect all requests to ASP.NET MVC on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I am probably overlooking something really simple here but I am trying to redirect all bad URLs to an action that filters the URL based on conditions and then either 301 redirects to a suitable page or issues a 404 page.

To this end I have a route like this at the end of my route table:

```
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Main", action = "Error" });
```

And an action like this:

```
public ActionResult Error(string url)
{
        if (/* Conditions are met... */)
        {
            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            Response.AddHeader("Location", /* Destination URL */);
            Response.End();
        }

        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View(/* 404 page... */));
}
```

This works perfectly locally.

However, when deployed to IIS6, URLs that don't include .mvc (e.g. oldfile.php) are never sent to the ASP.NET process for routing.

Is there a simple solution / am I overlooking something?

EDIT :
This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108813/404-http-error-handler-in-aspnet-mvc-rc-5), however under IIS6 URLs without .mvc are not being sent for ASP.NET MVC processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than likely when you deployed to the Server, ASP.Net is not being invoked.

I would setup wildcard mapping in IIS so your requests will use ASP.Net to serve the requests.

Open IIS manager, right-click your app, go to Properties, then Home Directory tab, then click Configuration. Under Wildcard application maps, click Insert (not Add, which is confusingly just above),  then enter C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll for “Executable”, and uncheck Verify that file exists.

For more information please visit the source that helped me with this issue at:  http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Comment: The first time I tried this I didn't notice that "Verify that file exists" needed to be unchecked.