# ASP.NET MVC Custom Error page (StatusCode 404 throws a 500)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I've got customErrors set in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/GeneralError">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

This works fine locally.  A 404 throws a 404.  On the shared hosting it throws up the standard server 404 page unless I specifically set 404 to point to /Error/NotFound.  That's fine.  Now it will show the custom 404 page except the response status code is 200.  So if I try to throw Response.StatusCode = 404; in my NotFound action in ErrorController like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```

the server throws a status code 500 Internal Server Error but my GeneralError page doesn't show, just a blank white page with no source.

I've tried many different combinations but I can't seem to find how to make it show my custom 404 page along with a 404 response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any harm in allowing it to respond with 200 OK on a NotFound?  Perhaps issues with web crawling or google webmaster tools.

Comment: Just a thought. Wouldn't it be better to use:
    defaultRedirect="~/Error/GeneralError" 
and 
    redirect="~/Error/NotFound"
with MVC applications. (Notice the ~ at the start of strings. This will map to the base of the application not the base of the domain... as you may know already.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found out some interesting information here: http://blog.angrypets.com/2008/03/responsetryskip.html

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Setting `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to `true` after the `Response.StatusCode = 404;` takes care of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `customErrors` element (except to turn `mode="On"` for local testing). Instead, add an `Application_EndRequest` method to your `MvcApplication` per [Marco's Better-Than-Unicorns MVC 404 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026907/145173).