# How to configure IIS to serve my 404 response with my custom content?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547582/asp-net-mvc-how-to-serve-content-while-returning-status-code-404), hopefully better phrased.

I would like to serve a custom 404 page from ASP.NET MVC. I have the route handler and all the infrastructure set up to ensure that nonexistent routes are handled by a single action:

```
public ActionResult Handle404()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View("NotFound");
}
```

**Problem: IIS serves back its own content (some predefined message)** when I set Response.StatusCode to 404 before returning the content.

On the VS development web server, this works as intended - the status code of the HTTP response is 404 while **my content (the NotFound view)** is served.

I believe that when the IIS processing pipeline sees that the application returns 404, it simply replaces the whole response with its own.

**What setting in IIS affects this behavior?**

I do not have access to the IIS installation so I can not investigate this - however, I can ask the hosting provider to tweak the configuration for me if I know what exactly needs to be changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: How to serve content while returning status code 404?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547582/asp-net-mvc-how-to-serve-content-while-returning-status-code-404)

Comment: Code similar to yours worked fine on IIS 7.5 on my Windows 7, but with the exact same files it did not work on several IIS 7.5 on Windows Server. There TrySkipIisCustomErrors helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376739/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-page-statuscode-404-throws-a-500/2376857#2376857) is the answer:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Comment: Note that this affects IIS 7+ only.

Comment: Yes, this works on IIS 7 and ASP.NET 3.5 only - fortunately, this is exactly my scenario.