# 404 Pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

I'm building my first ASP.NET MVC website, and I'm trying to figure out how to implement a 404 page.

Should I create a controller called "404Controller?" If so, how do I then register this Controller with IIS so that it redirects 404s to that page? Also, in a situation where something is not found (in the database, for example) by some other Controller code, how would I redirect the request to my 404 page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The favorite option for me is to return a view called 404.

```
if (article == null)
    return View("404");
```

This will let you the option to have a generic 404 view in the shared folder, and a specific 404 view to the article controller.

In addition, a big plus is that there is no redirect over here.

Comment: Simple and customizable, I like it.

Comment: don't forget about the unhandled events like bad urls. try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095

Comment: True, you have also to change the status code. But you get the point.

Answer (score 14):

There's no single answer for what your are trying to do, the simplest and what I like is using the `HttpException` class, e.g.

```
public ActionResult ProductDetails(int id) {

   Product p = this.repository.GetProductById(id);

   if (p == null) {
      throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
   }

   return View(p);
}
```

On web.config you can configure customError pages, e.g.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="Views/Errors/Http404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: The way IIS handles errors makes me sick. Don't redirect me just because I typed the URL incorrectly.

Comment: @David Murdoch: With `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` there's no redirection.

Comment: well, I feel much better now.   :-)

Comment: @UpTheCreek It does work if the error page does not depend on MVC.

Answer (score 4):

[MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) includes a `HttpNotFoundResult` class and `Controller` has a `HttpNotFound` static method too.

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id) {
        var myThing = Loader.GetById(id);
        if (myThing == null) {
            return HttpNotFound("Thing Not Found");
        }
        return View(myThing);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're correct, create a `NotFoundController` and map route to it, say `/404` and then put the URL in your `web.config` file (see @R0MANARMY) answer.
2. You can just `throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found")` or if you don't want to throw exceptions (which is costly) you can simply set the status code to 404 via `Response.StatusCode` property and then return a `View("My404Template")` from your action methods.

Comment: @chakrit: Won't asp.net mvc give you a 404 anyway without a NotFoundController?  Or do you mean in case you want to redirect to something other than a static html 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Application_EndRequest` method to your `MvcApplication` per [Marco's Better-Than-Unicorns MVC 404 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026907/145173). To cause a "not found" error from your code, throw `new HttpException(404, "Not Found")`.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone down the road...

Similar to Fitzchak's answer I have a custom 404 view in my shared folder.  To return the correct status code I simply added this to the top of that view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Not Found";
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

worked great on my localhost but on my production server I had to add this line to the web config because IIS was catching the 404 status and putting up it's own 404 page.

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```