# ASP.NET MVC - Show 404 Shared View WITHOUT a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm looking at [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/620559#620559) where the answerer shows a great way to throw a NotFoundException from the Application_Error method in the Global.asax.

This is great however I'd like to modify it a little... just not sure how.

I've got a NotFound view and a Error view in my Shared views folder.  I'd like to continue with this and not have to have an ErrorController.

Is there any way to throw a 404 NotFound error when a "controller" doesn't exist, while still not having to have an Error Controller?

IE: if you visit http://example.com/asdf whereby asdf is an invalid controller, I want the "NotFound" view to be loaded from my Shared views directory.

#### Edit

Basically the issue I'm running into is that of "DRY". I could build an ErrorController, however if I do this, then I have to have the **same view** in two spots.  One in my Views/Error folder for just this situation, and one in my Views/Shared folder whereby I can load up the Error or the NotFound View from any controller.

I also tried this

```
Private Sub BaseGlobal_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
    Dim exception As System.Exception = Server.GetLastError
    Response.Clear()

    Dim httpException As HttpException = TryCast(exception, HttpException)

    Dim routeData As RouteData = New RouteData()
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Events")

    If (Not httpException Is Nothing) And (httpException.GetHttpCode = 404) Then
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound")
        Server.ClearError()
        Dim errorController As IController = New UrbanNow.Core.Controllers.EventsController
        Response.StatusCode = 404
        errorController.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
    End If
End Sub
```

Where the EventsController is obviously for events, but tried to load in the NotFound view (hoping it would pull from the shared directory... but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Hmm now that I think about it... this might not be possible. Looking forward to hearing your input.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling) might be what you are looking for except you may not be able to put the page in the shared folder (to do that you might need a controler).

Comment: The "most upvoted" answer on that page says that you do it in the web.config. Problem with that is that it either requires a controller or a static page. Both of which I want to avoid. I'm trying to do it exclusively with my Shared controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a hack/work around solution to my problem, though it doesn't actually remove the need for a controller or a view

```
Private Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
    Dim exception As System.Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim httpException As HttpException = DirectCast(exception, HttpException)

    Dim routeData As New RouteData()
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error")

    If exception IsNot Nothing Then
        If httpException.GetHttpCode = 404 Then
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index")
            Server.ClearError()
            Dim errorController As IController = New MyApp.Core.Controllers.ErrorController
            Response.StatusCode = 404
            errorController.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically here I'm redirecting the user to the Error/Index page, but when they get there, this is what the Controller does

```
Public Class ErrorController : Inherits MyApp.Core.Base.BaseController
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Throw New ResourceNotFoundException
    End Function
End Class
```

This works, throws the appropriate error and takes them to the appropriate page... but it doesn't eliminate the need for a controller or a view... though the Index view is completely blank.

Comment: I would absolutely love to hear of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VirtualPathProvider. It's used by ASP.Net to find files (views).

Example code: http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2009/04/virtualpathprovider-example.html