# Send any invalid url or any url that doesn't exists to a custom controller in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

i am new in asp.net mvc3 . i am building my site in which i am facing a problem that i have a controller named `Home` and a method in it named `Index` and this index method takes a parameter id now according to this situation a valid url should be like this **"http://www. counterexample.com/Home/Index/1"** but what  should i do if a user types a url like this **"http://counterexample.com/whatsisthis"** . It will definately give `404` error but i want to do that when any one types a URL like this he should be redirected to my another controller named `Thunder` on method `ErrorDetails` and all the character which user types in url after / should come to this method as parameter like following

```
 public class ThunderController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ErrorDetails (string id)
    {
        var params = id ; // and the text "whatisthis" should store in param . 
        return View();
    }

}
```

Please note that user can type any url like

1. http://counterexample.com/whatsisthis/this
2. http://counterexample.com/whatsisthis/this/call

i want that all these URL or any URL that doesn't exists should redirect to my method 'ErrorDetails' . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) (web.config) like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Thunder/ErrorDetails/" />
   <!-- You can add other error codes or a generic one for other status codes here -->
</customErrors>
```

Comment: i want to to this from global.asax .

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling/9026907#9026907

Answer (score 1):

You can setup custom error on the web.config file.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Thunder/ErrorDetails/" />
 </customErrors>
```

Once 404 error was thrown, the user will be redirected to the ErrorDetails view.

Comment: your answer can solve my problem but i want to do this by routing in global.asax