# HttpErrors existingResponse="Replace" prevents custom error handling for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, http-status-code-404

I'm handling errors using the `[HandleError]` attribute from within an MVC3 application. This works fine but for this to work, I needed to add

```
<system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On" />
```

To handle 404 errors, I then added this to system.***webserver*** i.e. IIS config rather than asp.net

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
   <remove statusCode="404" />
   <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/404page" />
</httpErrors>
```

This is simple and works great for 404's. The reason for adding this here is that it seems like a good catch-all without any custom code. The existingResponse=**"Replace"** is required, other modes result in 404's not being handled.

The problem is that when existingResponse="Replace" the CustomErrors not longer functions. It just returns a stripped 500 error without details.

Are these two modes just mutually exclusive? I am aware that I can code other 404 solutions, but ideally I'd like this simple config change to work or understand why it just can't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but found [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026907/678453) worked for me instead of using `existingResponse="replace"`