# Avoid handle 404 on other requests than main

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, httprequest, global-asax

I used the method below in the `EndRequest` method from `global asax`. I get a `HTTP 404 error` even from image request or other requests. The point is that I want to check only for the first request/main request. Can you help me please. This is the only solution that works.

```
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        Response.Clear();

        var rd = new RouteData();
        rd.DataTokens["area"] = "AreaName"; 
        rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
        rd.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

        IController c = new ErrorsController();
        c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "main"? Are you only interested in handling 404s for controller actions?

Comment: by main let say you make a request to http://www.microsoft.comand if you lock in firebug you will see server other requests for images and stuff

Comment: put your error here. (stacktrace)

Comment: is not an error with stack tree the point in here is that you got a 404 request. This request can come from mysite.com/blabla <- here you will get a 404 page not found. but 404 you get even if in your site have a request of a image like /myImage.jpg or someother url is not found. What i want to get is the 404 only for mysite.com/blabla. here you can read about this 404 request more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling on the answer of Marco (35 ups)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to only handle 404s for controller actions you can check whether or not the current request is for one like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")))
{
  ...handling code goes here....
}
```

Comment: not really i should force him to go in a specific controller and base on the name(some url are known in the db as rots to redirect) so i cannot take this option. There on that unknown links can be a redirect page to some other page from website but i cannot make a difference between them until i get to the specify controller for 404. but i do not get in there with other requests like a image requests.

Comment: Then you need to use a regex against the Url or something like that.