# Where does <customErrors> in web.config go for MVC applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I'm attempting to implement custom error handling in my MVC 4 app. I'm not certain where in my web.config the `<customErrors>` is supposed to go, and the general information I need to include in it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`<customErrors>` goes inside `<system.web>`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
            <error statusCode="500"
                   redirect="~/Error/InternalServer" />
            <error statusCode="404"
                   redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Modify values of the `redirect` attributes according to your routes. You can also implement a catch-all redirect by adding a `defaultRedirect` attribute to the `customErrors` element. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In web.config file under root directory

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

> Create a shared folder under view folder, and create a view under shared folder for showing Error message
>
> in action use that [HandleError] like

```
[HandleError]
    public ActionResult Errors()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```