# Custom Error redirection does not work in ASP.NET MVC Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

In my application I have included `<customerror>` tag in Web.config as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/404"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/403"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/500"/>
</customErrors>
```

I have created an entry in my route config such that any request with url pattern **/Error/{status}** goes to a specific controller action with **status** as a parameter.

And I have a custom ActionFilterAttribute which checks whether the user is admin and returns an HTTP 403 result if not. Following is my custom filter attribute.

```
public class RequireAdminAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!UserOperations.IsAdmin())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new Http403Result();
        }
    }
}

internal class Http403Result : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // Set the response code to 403.
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
}
```

Now, what I need is user to be redirect to the **/Error/403** page if he is not authorized. When I run my application, my applition does not redirect to the error page when 403 error occurs. If a 404 error occurs, it redirects to the given 404 error page (in most cases when 404 occurs). What is the reason for this? Can anybody give me a solution? Do I need to hardcode redirection to error page using something like `RedirectToRouteResult`?

**Edit**:
In some cases redirection does not work where I explicitely used `return HttpNotFound();` result as well. I would like to know whether using `return HttpNotFound();` does not redirect to a custom page.

Thank you.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251134/where-does-customerrors-in-web-config-go-for-mvc-applications

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this to your `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom"  defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="403" path="/Error/403" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I replaced path `attribute` mentioned in your answer in `error` tag to `/Error/403` and retried. But no luck.

Comment: What is the result? Also, what version of IIS?

Comment: Its IIS 8, still the detailed error page is displayed.