# How to handle error using TemData[ ] in asp.net mvc?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to handle following errors using TempData:

1) My custom Error defined by me if certain condition is not fulfilled.

2) To display the exact SQL-server error.

Note: I am Using Redirect after the code.

Comment: Here is a good read on this topic 

[enter link description here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling

Comment: You should not redirect in case of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need like this: In the controller

```
public ActionResult SaveProduct(Product model)
   {
      var ErrorString = null;

      // your custom validations for example,
      if(model.Name == null) ErrorString = "Name is empty";

      try
      {
         // your db save operations 
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
         ErrorString = exception.Message;
      }

      if(ErrorString != null) TempData["Error"] = ErrorString;
      return Redirect("YourAction"); 
    }
```

And in View:

```
@{
    var error = (string)TempData["Error"];
}


@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
       <p>@Html.Raw(error)</p>
    }
```