# Execute action in other controller on 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to return a action "PageNotFound" that resides in my "Error"-controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
 public BaseController()
 {
 }

 public BaseController(IContentRepository contentRep, ILocalizedRepository localRep)
 {
    this._localRep = localRep;
    this._contentRep = contentRep;
 }

 protected new HttpNotFoundResult HttpNotFound(string statusDescription = null)
 {
    return new HttpNotFoundResult(statusDescription);
 }

protected HttpUnauthorizedResult HttpUnauthorized(string statusDescription = null)
{
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(statusDescription);
}

 protected class HttpNotFoundResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
 {
    public HttpNotFoundResult() : this(null) { }

    public HttpNotFoundResult(string statusDescription) : base(404, statusDescription) { }
 }

 protected class HttpUnauthorizedResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
 {
    public HttpUnauthorizedResult(string statusDescription) : base(401, statusDescription) { }
 }

 protected class HttpStatusCodeResult : ViewResult
 {
    public int StatusCode { get; private set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; private set; }

    public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode) : this(statusCode, null) { }

    public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode, string statusDescription)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
        this.StatusDescription = statusDescription;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = this.StatusCode;
        if (this.StatusDescription != null)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = this.StatusDescription;
        }

        this.ViewName = "PageNotFound";  // CONTROLLER MISSING
        this.ViewBag.Message = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription;
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
     }
 }
```

How can I modify it so it returns the "PageNotFound" action in the "Error"- controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why you want to make a redirect. I would return 404

```
return HttpStatusCode(404);
```

And then use the approach described here: [ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling) to render the correct view. Benefit: your url is still the same, much easier for error handling and for the browser history.

Answer (score 2):

A `ViewResult` is supposed to directly render a view (optionally passing a model and a layout). There's no controller involved in this process.

If you want to go through a controller you need to perform redirect, i.e. use `RedirectToRouteResult` instead of `ViewResult`.

In your example you are using this custom ViewResult directly inside some other controller. So that will be the controller that will render the error view.

Comment: How should I implement that since I cant return new RedirectToRouteResult in a void function (?)

Comment: Your base class should be `RedirectToRouteResult` instead of `ViewResult` in this case. Then you will have the possibility of passing the values for the action and controller when calling the base constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
return RedirectToAction("PageNotFound", "ControllerName");
```