# custom errors on the server in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have got a problem with my application in asp.net mvc 5. I try to create custom error views. I create it by sites: 
[first site](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html),
[second site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366170/asp-net-mvc-5-http-error-404-0-not-found-with-long-non-existing-url)

when application is running like local site, everything works fine, but when i deploy it on the server, custom error pages dont work.

In web config my code looks like:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Error500.cshtml" >
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/Error500.cshtml"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/Error404.cshtml"/>
</customErrors>
```

...

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/ErrorPages/Error/Error500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/Error/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Error Controller:

```
public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;

        return View();
    }
```

and view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error404";
}
```

Someone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `path="/ErrorPages/Error500"`

Comment: Area - ErrorPages, Controller - Error, Action - Error500

Comment: add @Response.StatusCode=404 in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure the reason it's not working when you're deploying is because you're running different IIS versions.

Have a look at Marco's answer in this thread. I can't explain it better:
[ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks, for your response. Working fine