# How to handle 404 error for files in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I wrote Controller to handle 404-page error for my MVC5 application as it was showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366170/asp-net-mvc-5-http-error-404-0-not-found-with-long-non-existing-url). However it works only with HTML-pages that has controller and method.

It doesn't work with files\images that just has a link inside the site. 
For example Sample.chtml:

```
    <a href="@material.FilePath"><i class="material-icons left">file_download</i>@material.Title</a>`
```

where FilePath is just reference to ~Content/images/... or ~/Content/Files/file.pdf.

When I try to go through this links I get standard 404 NotFound page and Error controller or Application_Error from Global.asax.cs doesn't call.

Especially I need this handler for file-not-found case. 
How can I solve this problem?

Edited : Important moment : this files has just pure-html-link and no controller\method defined.

Comment: Check this out https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging, http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages you need to get past IIS default error pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search NuGet for the MvcNotFound package. It handles all of this very neatly for you.