# ASP MVC not displaying proper error pages based on httpErrors configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am using the latest version of `ASP.NET MVC 5` for my web application and it is running through `IIS 7.5` which came with `Windows 7`. I am struggling to implement `httpErrors` in the web.config and to have my breakpoint reached in my error controller.

I have experimented with displaying HTML files and displaying a view from my error controller as error messages. This is my current setup in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
          <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="500" path="Http500.html" responseMode="File" />
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I do have an ErrorController class. There is a directory under Views called Error. And in the Error directory are 2 files:

- Http404.cshtml
- Http500.cshtml

When I typed in `www.mywebsite.com/foo` the following happens:

- The Application_Error method is hit
- The breakpoint in the Http404 action method in my error controller is not hit
- The page displayed to me is white, nothing on it
- Google Chrome shows me that an HTTP 403 forbidden error was thrown

When I typed in `www.mywebsite.com/foo.html` the following happens:

- The Application_Error method is not hit
- The breakpoint in the Http404 action method in my error controller is not hit
- The page displayed to me is white, nothing on it
- Google Chrome shows me that an HTTP 403 forbidden error was thrown

When I change the the httpErrors configuration to that of below then my static HTML page is displayed with the correct HTTP 404 not found error:

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
          <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="Http404.html" responseMode="File" />
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I have nothing in my Application_Error method:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
}
```

And this what my error controller looks like:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Http404()
     {
          // Not sure if this is needed?
          Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

          return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Http500()
     {
          // Not sure if this is needed?
          Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

          return View();
     }
}
```

I removed the `customErrors` configuration from the web.config.

I have the following questions:

- How do I get this fixed to display my views in my error controller?
- Why are some errors hitting the Application_Error method and others not?
- How do I know if it is an ASP MVC error or an IIS error?
- Some errors are caught in Application_Error and others not, how do I log all of them?

Comment: Also check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling

Comment: Why was my question closed? If it is a repeat or not I still have unanswered questions!