# Handling 404 error in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to redirect user to an controller action while there is any 404 found. Like missing Controller or missing action or bad URL.
I am using below approach :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageNotFound" />
</httpErrors>
```

But the issues is my action(pageNotFound) is called every time I request a URL. Even if the URL is valid.This may kill performance during production deployment. Any suggestion or another approach

Comment: [Check this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound" />
</customErrors>
```