# Getting the original requested URL before custom error handling Redirect in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using custom error handling in ASP.NET MVC4 for redirecting to a custom error page when a 404 status is caught.

The code is as follows

---

### Web.Config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFoundError"/>   
</customErrors>
```

---

### Error Controller

```
    public ActionResult NotFoundError()
    {
        string originalUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        Errormodel model = new Errormodel();
        model.URL = originalUrl ;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Notice that I use the Request.Url.AbsolutePath property on the Request object to get the URL.

The problem is that I would like to get the original URL that I targeted before the redirect in order to show it in my view, and instead I get the url to the custom error page.

**Example in View**

> You requested http://testproject/test which was not found.

How could I get the original target URL as opposed to the new custom error page URL?

Comment: Have you tried Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath?

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer appears to be returning null for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer 
[ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Basicaly it using function Application_EndRequest event to add any information before go to new action

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            var rd = new RouteData();
            rd.DataTokens["area"] = "AreaName"; // In case controller is in another area
            rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
            rd.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

            IController c = new ErrorsController();
            c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
        }
    }
}
```