# instead of error page redirection show error message in live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-error

I want to redirect to error page when http error occurs in my web site and it  is working well in locally but in live site returns messages instead of default redirection.

i use following code part in web config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poxf0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove **existingResponse='replace'** other wise follow below link
[Error Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling/9026907#9026907)