# How to support virtual files in a C# MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a catch-all website where users can upload their own html code to the website then the website will show their website when their call the specific subdomain.

The html code with attachments get's uploaded to a subdirectory inside the website:

```
SITE #1
~/sites/test1/index.html
~/sites/test1/images/logo.png

SITE #2
~/sites/test2/index.html
~/sites/test2/images/logo.png
```

So you can call these files using the following urls:

```
SITE #1
http://test1.mydomain.com/index.html
http://test1.mydomain.com/images/logo.png

SITE #2
http://test2.mydomain.com/index.html
http://test2.mydomain.com/images/logo.png
```

So what I did was make error handler inside the global.asax that detects when you try to request a file that doesn't exist, hence request the website:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    // Get the subdomain requested
    var subdomain = Request.Url.Authority.Split(new char[] { '.', ':' }).FirstOrDefault();

    // Get the directory info about the requested subdomain
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + subdomain));

    // Check if subdomain is not empty and exists
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subdomain) && info.Exists)
    {
        // Get the requested filename
        var filename = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Split(new char[] { '?' }).FirstOrDefault();

        // If the root is requested change to index.html
        if (filename == "/") filename = "/index.html";

        // Translate requested filename to server path
        var fullname = Server.MapPath("~/sites/" + subdomain + filename);

        // Respond the file
        ResponseFile(fullname);
    }
    else
    {
        // Subdomain not found so end the request
        Response.End();
    }
}

public void ResponseFile(string fullname)
{
    Response.Clear();

    System.IO.Stream oStream = null;

    try
    {
        // Open the file
        oStream =
            new System.IO.FileStream
                (path: fullname,
                mode: System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                share: System.IO.FileShare.Read,
                access: System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        // **************************************************
        Response.Buffer = false;

        // Setting the ContentType
        Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullname);

        // Get the length of the file 
        long lngFileLength = oStream.Length;

        // Notify user (client) the total file length
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lngFileLength.ToString());
        // **************************************************

        // Total bytes that should be read
        long lngDataToRead = lngFileLength;

        // Read the bytes of file
        while (lngDataToRead > 0)
        {
            // The below code is just for testing! So we commented it!
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

            // Verify that the client is connected or not?
            if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // 8KB
                int intBufferSize = 8 * 1024;

                // Create buffer for reading [intBufferSize] bytes from file
                byte[] bytBuffers =
                    new System.Byte[intBufferSize];

                // Read the data and put it in the buffer.
                int intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream =
                    oStream.Read(buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0, count: intBufferSize);

                // Write the data from buffer to the current output stream.
                Response.OutputStream.Write
                    (buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0,
                    count: intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream);

                // Flush (Send) the data to output
                // (Don't buffer in server's RAM!)
                Response.Flush();

                lngDataToRead =
                    lngDataToRead - intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream;
            }
            else
            {
                // Prevent infinite loop if user disconnected!
                lngDataToRead = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        if (oStream != null)
        {
            //Close the file.
            oStream.Close();
            oStream.Dispose();
            oStream = null;
        }
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

The code above works for the "/index.html" file, but it doesn't work for the "/images/logo.png" because the 404 will not fire the Application_Error handler. After a lot of searching and pulling my hair out I found out this "feature" started from .net 4.0 and above. But I do not want to go back, I want to know how to properly solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AaronLS, I began searching how to make a custom handler that would catch all requests. Too bad it wasn't so easy to find.

First of all, you need to inform IIS that you want to handle all files by updating the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

(I don't know it the *httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"* really is needed, might have been some previous solution I tried)

Then I needed to make my own custom handler and set it up in the routeconfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // So my users can still login
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Account",
            url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // For the upload controller to work
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Upload",
            url: "Upload/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Upload", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // And finally registrating my custom handler
        routes.Add(new Route("{*path}", new CustomRouteHandler()));

        // This was the original routeconfig
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
}
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new CustomHttpHandler();
    }
}
public class CustomHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get the subdomain requested
        var subdomain = context.Request.Url.Authority.Split(new char[] { '.', ':' }).FirstOrDefault();

        // Get the directory info about the requested subdomain
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(context.Server.MapPath("~/Websites/" + subdomain));

        // Check if subdomain is not empty and exists
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subdomain) && info.Exists)
        {
            // Get the requested filename
            var filename = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Split(new char[] { '?' }).FirstOrDefault();

            // If the root is requested change to index.html
            if (filename == "/") filename = "/index.html";

            // Translate requested filename to server path
            var fullname = context.Server.MapPath("~/Websites/" + subdomain + filename);

            // Respond the file
            ResponseFile(context, fullname);
        }
        else
        {
            // Subdomain not found so end the request
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
    public void ResponseFile(HttpContext context, string fullname)
    {
        // Clear the response buffer
        context.Response.Clear();

        System.IO.Stream oStream = null;

        try
        {
            // Open the file
            oStream =
                new System.IO.FileStream
                    (path: fullname,
                    mode: System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                    share: System.IO.FileShare.Read,
                    access: System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            // **************************************************
            context.Response.Buffer = false;

            // Setting the ContentType
            context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullname);

            // Get the length of the file 
            long lngFileLength = oStream.Length;

            // Notify user (client) the total file length
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lngFileLength.ToString());
            // **************************************************

            // Total bytes that should be read
            long lngDataToRead = lngFileLength;

            // Read the bytes of file
            while (lngDataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected or not?
                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // 8KB
                    int intBufferSize = 8 * 1024;

                    // Create buffer for reading [intBufferSize] bytes from file
                    byte[] bytBuffers =
                        new System.Byte[intBufferSize];

                    // Read the data and put it in the buffer.
                    int intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream =
                        oStream.Read(buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0, count: intBufferSize);

                    // Write the data from buffer to the current output stream.
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write
                        (buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0,
                        count: intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream);

                    // Flush (Send) the data to output
                    // (Don't buffer in server's RAM!)
                    context.Response.Flush();

                    lngDataToRead =
                        lngDataToRead - intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Prevent infinite loop if user disconnected!
                    lngDataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                oStream.Close();
                oStream.Dispose();
                oStream = null;
            }
            context.Response.Close();
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Waiting until application error is a little late in the pipeline.  One way is to create a custom handler, and using a custom route to detect virtual files map those requests to the handler.  This means you need to generate links to virtual files using a predictable pattern, perhaps making a path such as /SpecialFiles/:

```
routes.Add(new Route("SpecialFiles/{*path}", new SomeFileHandler()));
```

You could also map this to a a controller action, and let the action parse the URL/query string and return a file response.

Either approach allows you to specify a route with various parameters, such as a highly random token that is needed to access the file similar to "shared file" links seen in other systems.   You could configure the route to match on particular file extensions.  The options are pretty varied.  Just like any other route, you can push different pieces of the path into variables, or you can just access the URL directly from the Request once you get into your handler or action and parse it manually.