# How to display a custom 404-error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created one demo for show our custom error page in MVC 5. I am having success when entering two slashes, but when I am entering more than two slashes, I am not getting my custom error page, but rather a MVC error as shown below.

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This is how my `Web.config` file looks like.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
    <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" statusCode="403" />
</customErrors>
```

This is my `ErrorController`.

```
public ViewResult NotFound()
{
    return View();
}
```

My current setup works fine when I enter the URL below.

> http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf

But when enter one of the URLs below, my custom error page is not displayed.

> http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf/sdsdsd/asdsadasd/dasdsad 
>   http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf/dsads/fe

Comment: A 404 is appropriate here.  An error page is displayed when there's an error in the application. If the end user uses a invalid URL the web server itself will respond with a 404. If the application doesn't recognize a URL it won't even try to process it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with slashes. What is this URL supposed to represent? A subsite calles `search` with an area called `fdsfdf`, a `dsads` controller that accepts an ID parameter with the value `fe`? Or did you intend to create a `SearchController` with a `Get` method that accepts 3 parameters specified in the route? And another with 5 parameters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my search controller have one name of method detail method and I am type search/fdsfdf/dsads like this then In my search controller can't have any name of the method fdsfdf so conceptually my url is wrong so why my custom page is not show there?

Comment: You'll find the explanation and workarounds in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling/9026907), especially the most voted answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried all way but still getting the same issue so can you please help me on that how can I fix this issue??

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing comes down to the fact that some errors are handled by ASP.NET and others by IIS. You can read more on that topic [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages).

I would suggest you create an `ErrorsController`, which handles the most common application errors and returns the respective views. Additionally, you have to configure your `Web.config` (or `Web.Release.config`) file to use the newly created controller and you also might have to replace the default error pages of your IIS (for me, they are located within the `InetPub\custerr\en-US\` directory).

**Controller** *(ErrorsController.cs)*

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Errors/Unauthorized
    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
    }

    // GET: Errors/Forbidden
    public ActionResult Forbidden()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
    }

    // Additional Errors
}
```

**Configuration File** *(Web.Release.config)*

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/" mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Errors/Unauthorized"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Errors/Forbidden"/>
  <!-- Additional Errors -->
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I have try but still getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

Default `/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` have

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

so you enter `http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf` or `http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf/1234` will get httpStatusCode 200,but `http://localhost:14360/search/fdsfdf/dsads/fe` is undefine url, asp.net will return 404 to browser
if you need custom error page, try add `httpErrors` and `customErrors` handle httpStatusCode 404

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto" errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/404" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
        <error redirect="~/Error/404" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: It's not that easy. Check the duplicate

Comment: I have try but I still getting same issue.