# Is it possible to get routedebbuger result when user hits 404?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

May be I'm missing something, but the way now routedebbuger works (2+ version) is that it renders it's results on end of the page, which may be useful sometimes, but more often is annoying.

Would it be possible to return routedebbuger results only in case, when page is not found, when probability that our routing does not work as it supposed to work is the highest? In such case I would get information what is wrong right away, when I need it most (sure, this behavour would be enabled only in debug mode) .

If so, how to do that?

Comment: better ask the guy who made it :D http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx

Comment: hm, is the question not clear or nobody knows how to do it? :)

Comment: it is clear, probably people who saw your question are not familiar with routedebugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [custom error controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108813/404-http-error-handler-in-asp-net-mvc-rc-5) and 404 view, you can use the version of Phil Haack's  [route debugger code that I put together to serve as a control](http://georgestocker.com/2011/04/15/route-debugging-control-for-asp-net-mvc/) on each page, which will be served even if you hit a 404.